# MSSQL: update matching rows from the uploaded file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Help me guys, I want to update my existing table from the uploaded files, but I am having a trouble on the part where the update starts, I want to match the reference number of from the table so it will select the right row to update.

```
USE [RMT]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[gen048update]    Script Date: 03/29/2016 08:35:52 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      
-- Create date: 
-- Description: Upload data
-- =============================================
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[gen048update]
(
        @fileDate VARCHAR(20)
)


AS BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON

declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX),

@dynamic varchar(8000),
@tablesuffix varchar(8),
@refd varchar(30),
@refcnt varchar(30)



select @refd=(SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 102), '.', '') AS [MMDDYYYY])
select @tablesuffix=(SELECT REPLACE(UPPER(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(11), GETDATE(), 106), 8)), '', '') AS [Mon-YYYY])
--print @tablesuffix
--convert(varchar,day(convert(datetime, @fileDate)))+upper(substring(datename(m,convert(datetime,@fileDate)),1,3))+convert(varchar,year(convert(datetime,@fileDate)))


--**COMPOSE FIGURE COLUMNS
 declare @currmonth varchar(10)
 select @dynamic=''

create table #logs(
i int identity(1,1),
tableName varchar(50),

status varchar(30)
)

--SELECT getdate()

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    CREATE TABLE #temp (WHOLEROW VARCHAR(8000))

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temp

    CREATE TABLE #temp1 (WHOLEROW VARCHAR(8000))

    --BEGIN TRY

        BEGIN TRANSACTION

        DECLARE @SQL2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
        SET @SQL2 = 'BULK INSERT #temp1
        FROM ''Y:\FTP\RMT\RMT\gen048\delivery\' + @fileDate + '.txt' + '''
        WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'', KEEPNULLS, FIRSTROW=1, MAXERRORS=0, ROWTERMINATOR =  ''' + CHAR(0x0A) + ''')'

;WITH Splitted(AsXml) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t1.WHOLEROW,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
    FROM #records AS t1
)
SELECT AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS ID
      ,ID_Splitted.*
      ,AsXml.value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS FSI_Field
      ,AsXml.value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS CAPTION
      ,AsXml.value('x[4]','varchar(max)') AS STATUS
      ,AsXml.value('x[5]','varchar(max)') AS NUMBER
      ,AsXml.value('x[6]','varchar(max)') AS Fld1
      ,AsXml.value('x[7]','varchar(max)') AS Fld2
      ,AsXml.value('x[8]','varchar(max)') AS Fld3
      ,AsXml.value('x[9]','varchar(max)') AS Fld4
      ,AsXml.value('x[10]','varchar(max)') AS TARGET
      ,AsXml.value('x[11]','varchar(max)') AS TARGET_TYPE
      ,AsXml.value('x[12]','varchar(max)') AS TARGET_NUMBER
INTO #temp2
FROM Splitted
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEFT( AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(max)'),1) AS FirstLetter
                  ,CAST(SUBSTRING(AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(max)'),2,8) AS DATE) AS IncludedDate
                  ,CAST(SUBSTRING( AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(max)'),11,100)  AS INT) AS IncludedNumber) AS ID_Splitted;

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL2

declare @sourceTable varchar(500)
declare @year varchar(22)
declare @month varchar(3)
declare @test varchar(11)
declare @result varchar(8)
declare @index int

declare @string varchar(15)
set @string = (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 1 REPLACE(dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW, '|', 0), CHAR(9), '') FROM #temp1)
set @test = (select UPPER(convert(datetime,substring(@string,2,charindex('-',@string,1)-2))))
--select @test

set @month =(left(@test,3))

set @year = (right(@test,4))
--select @year

set @result = @month + @year
-- select @result

set @sourceTable = 'gen_048_'+@result
select @sourceTable

declare @ref varchar(255)
SET @ref = 'select convert(varchar(55),refdate)+''-''+convert(varchar(55),refcount)'
select @ref

declare @string2 varchar(255)
SET @string2 = 'select convert(varchar(55),refdate)+''-''+convert(varchar(55),refcount) FROM '
               + Quotename(@sourceTable)
print @string2
EXEC (@string2)

set @index = 1




SELECT * FROM #temp2;

DROP TABLE #temp2;
DROP TABLE #temp1;


declare @refnum varchar(100)
declare @stat varchar(100)
declare @statdate varchar(100)


WHILE (@index <= (SELECT MAX([index]) FROM #records))


        BEGIN

        set @stat = (select stat from #records where [index] = @index)
        select @stat

        set @statdate = (select statdate from #records where [index] = @index)
        select @statdate

        set @refnum = (select refnum from #records where [index] = @index)
        set @refnum = replace(@refnum, 'F', '')

        select @refnum
        --  = '+@refnum+'(courier, stat, statdate, stat2, statdate2, stat3, statdate3, recvby, rel, pupdate)
        select * from #records

                        --(select UPPER(convert(datetime,substring(@string,2,charindex('-',@string,1)-2))))
        set @sql = '
            MERGE gen_048_MAR2016 target
            USING #records source
                ON target.refdate'+'-'+'select convert(varchar(20), target.refcount) = (select substring(source.refnum, 2, 13))
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE
                    SET
                    target.stat = source.stat

            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
              INSERT (stat, statdate)
              VALUES (source.stat, source.statdate)                 
                ;'
                select @refnum, @stat, @statdate
                print @sql
                exec (@sql)

            SELECT 'File has been successfully uploaded', @fileDate,'success' as msg

          set @index = @index + 1

       END

        COMMIT TRANSACTION

END
```

Comment: You tag with MySql and SQL Server. Please tag the actual RDBMS (I suppose its SQL Server...) From your code one can see, that you are loading. Is `WHOLEROW` a column of your table `#temp`? How are you fill this table? Please show what the data looks like. And show the structure of your target tabel. I'm pretty sure, that this might be done much easier...

Comment: Sorry I just clicked all the recommended tags I didn't notice the MySQL, the `WHOLEROW` is from the data that I am uploading that 0 or 1st row from that upload file is the reference code Ex. F20160316-1000 and I am matching it to my current data from the table in variable `@string2`

Comment: Hi Vince. I'm not sitting right beside you... Please show the data (some rows) and the structure of your target table. Is this table empty? Are all rows new data or all rows existing data or might be both? Read about `MERGE` Please tell me how you load this file.

Comment: Sorry, I already uploaded the table, and the file that will upload to update the table above, I also edited it with my recent codes because I've read some about temp table and looping because I think that is what I need there.

Comment: Hi Vince, whenever you poste something, **please avoid images**! It is much harder to create a test scenario if you have to type it out...

Comment: Okay Im sorry! im going to delete this question now since its very vague and hard to understand. I dont event know how to explain things properly.

Comment: Hi hang on! I just posted an answer...

Comment: I already edited my codes, I can now get the right format of the uploaded file to match it to the table that I am going to update. please check the `set @sql` part im really sorry for my poor english and I have this flu for 2 days now so I am really having a hard time Sir.

Comment: If you place my code (starting with the `;WITH ...` down to `... AS ID_Splitted;` right behind your `EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL2` you'd get the data in a nice table structure with all information you need. The rest should be easy...

Comment: ok sir will do that, I will try your codes now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a much easier approach to get into your pipe delimited data. You find your table-like data within #temp2. From here on it should be easy to `UPDATE`,`INSERT` or `MERGE` your data into your target.

Attention: I could just guess the meaning of your columns, so the column names might be rubbish...

```
CREATE TABLE #temp1(WHOLEROW VARCHAR(8000));
INSERT INTO #temp1 VALUES
 ('F20160323-1000|FSI|BISCOCHO|DELIVERED|42317|||||GINA T|TENANT|42311')
,('F20160323-1001|FSI|MARTINNE|DELIVERED|42314|||||MERLIE STRADA|IN LAW|42311')
,('F20160323-1002|FSI|MANALO|DELIVERED|42313|||||GINA A|TENANT|42311')
,('F20160323-1004|FSI|HAMOY CAJAYON|DELIVERED|42311|||||MERLIE QTRADA|IN LAW|42311')
,('F20160323-1003|FSI|FRANCISCA|DELIVERED|42312|||||GINA B|TENANT|42311')
,('F20160323-1005|FSI|NINA|DELIVERED|42318|||||MERLIE STRADA|IN LAW|42311');

;WITH Splitted(AsXml) AS
(
    SELECT CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(t1.WHOLEROW,'|','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML)
    FROM #temp1 AS t1
)
SELECT AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(max)') AS ID
      ,ID_Splitted.*
      ,AsXml.value('x[2]','varchar(max)') AS FSI_Field
      ,AsXml.value('x[3]','varchar(max)') AS CAPTION
      ,AsXml.value('x[4]','varchar(max)') AS STATUS
      ,AsXml.value('x[5]','varchar(max)') AS NUMBER
      ,AsXml.value('x[6]','varchar(max)') AS Fld1
      ,AsXml.value('x[7]','varchar(max)') AS Fld2
      ,AsXml.value('x[8]','varchar(max)') AS Fld3
      ,AsXml.value('x[9]','varchar(max)') AS Fld4
      ,AsXml.value('x[10]','varchar(max)') AS TARGET
      ,AsXml.value('x[11]','varchar(max)') AS TARGET_TYPE
      ,AsXml.value('x[12]','varchar(max)') AS TARGET_NUMBER
INTO #temp2
FROM Splitted
CROSS APPLY(SELECT LEFT( AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(max)'),1) AS FirstLetter
                  ,CAST(SUBSTRING(AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(max)'),2,8) AS DATE) AS IncludedDate
                  ,CAST(SUBSTRING( AsXml.value('x[1]','varchar(max)'),11,100)  AS INT) AS IncludedNumber) AS ID_Splitted;

SELECT * FROM #temp2;

DROP TABLE #temp2;
DROP TABLE #temp1;
```

The result

```
ID         FirstLetter  IncludedDate    InclNmbr    FSI CAPTION      STATUS     NUMBER  TARGET          TYPE    NUMBER
F20160323-1000  F       2016-03-23      1000        FSI BISCOCHO     DELIVERED  42317   GINA T          TENANT  42311
F20160323-1001  F       2016-03-23      1001        FSI MARTINNE     DELIVERED  42314   MERLIE STRADA   IN LAW  42311
F20160323-1002  F       2016-03-23      1002        FSI MANALO       DELIVERED  42313   GINA A          TENANT  42311
F20160323-1004  F       2016-03-23      1004        FSI HAMOY CAJAYONDELIVERED  42311   MERLIE QTRADA   IN LAW  42311
F20160323-1003  F       2016-03-23      1003        FSI FRANCISCA    DELIVERED  42312   GINA B          TENANT  42311
F20160323-1005  F       2016-03-23      1005        FSI NINA         DELIVERED  42318   MERLIE STRADA   IN LAW  42311
```

Comment: The `VALUES` that I am using will be from the uploaded file

Comment: @VinceOsana, in your own code you do a `BULK INSERT` from the file into `#temp1`. My code inserts some test data, so just start with the `;WITH ...` After the call you'll find all your data in `#temp2`. Where is your problem? You might out-comment the `DROP TABLE` statements at the end...

Comment: I am really lost with this codes right now because I just got all of this from different dimensions and I cant understand it now. I pasted the entire codes from my query now.

Comment: @VinceOsana, just try to place the `;WITH Splitted ... AS ID_Splitted` right behind your `EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL2` No need to create a new table ` #records` ...

Comment: `Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure gen048update, Line 60
Invalid object name '#records'.
Msg 266, Level 16, State 2, Procedure gen048update, Line 60
Transaction count after EXECUTE indicates a mismatching number of BEGIN and COMMIT statements. Previous count = 0, current count = 1.
`

Comment: @VinceOsana, You changed my code to use a new `#records` table. No need for this. Just take the specified part freshly out of my answer and try it again...

Comment: Nevermind I will just change my project. I can't understand it anymore. thank you for your effort Sir~!

Comment: @VinceOsana, your last edit took away the execution of your `BULK INSERT`. It's not that difficult... First step: Read your file data row wise into #temp1. Second step: Use my code to create and fill #temp2. Third step: Look into #temp2 and be happy :-)

Comment: Sorry I was stressed last night because of my deadline and I dont want to have a failing grade :(

Comment: @VinceOsana No problem! Stress is no fun... Good luck with your grades!