# SQL Server replace function inside of merge operation

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I want to match the temp variable to my table column to merge its contents, but my temp variable contains a letter and I need to remove it to match the two columns from my table. I dont know what is the right code for this.

This is the content of the temp table

> F20151103-1010|FSI|FRANCISCA MANALO BISCOCHO|DELIVERED|42317
>
> F20151103-1019|FSI|NINA MARTINNE HAMOY CAJAYON|DELIVERED|42314

```
CREATE TABLE #records(
         [index] int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY
        ,refnum varchar(200)
        ,stat varchar(200)
        ,statdate varchar(200)
    )

insert into #records (refnum, stat, statdate) 
select 
dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',0),
dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',3),
dbo.fn_Parsename(WHOLEROW,'|',4)

from #temp1
declare @refnum varchar(100)
declare @stat varchar(100)
declare @statdate varchar(100)

BEGIN

WHILE (@index <= (SELECT MAX([index]) FROM #records))

    set @sql = '
        MERGE gen_048_MAR2016 target
        USING #records source
            ON target.refdate'+'-'+'target.refcount = source.'+replace(refnum, 'F', '')+'
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE
                SET
                target.stat = source.stat
                
        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
          INSERT (stat, statdate)
          VALUES (source.stat, source.statdate)                 
            ;'
            select @refnum, @stat, @statdate
            print @sql
            exec (@sql)

           SELECT 'File has been successfully uploaded', @fileDate,'success' as msg

      set @index = @index + 1

   END
```

ERROR:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'F20160323-1000' to data type int.

Comment: You should add your entire statement. It is not completely clear if you are correctly creating dynamic SQL. But single quotes inside strings should turn into 2 single quotes.

Comment: On the second sight the `from #records` is wrong. On the very first sight the whole statement is - uhm - *unclear* ... All these quotes... Please poste the whole statement!

Comment: What is wrong with my answer I gave you here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36173142/5089204? You should use this to get your data as derived table and then do the `MERGE` from there without the need to use a loop (*urgh*) and dynamic SQL (*urgh in most cases*)...

Answer (score 0):

Could you try replacing

`'+'-'+'` with `+''-''+`

```
set @sql = '
        MERGE gen_048_MAR2016 target
        USING #records source
            ON target.refdate+''-''+target.refcount = source.'+replace(refnum, 'F', '')+'
        WHEN MATCHED THEN
            UPDATE
                SET
                target.stat = source.stat

        WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
          INSERT (stat, statdate)
          VALUES (source.stat, source.statdate)                 
            ;'
```

EDIT:
target.refdate'+'-'+'target.refcount is not contactination. 
You are subtracting the 2 columns.

Why not just add the 'F' to the other side?

```
set @sql = '
            MERGE gen_048_MAR2016 target
            USING #records source
                ON ''F''+target.refdate+''-''+target.refcount = source.refnum
            WHEN MATCHED THEN
                UPDATE
                    SET
                    target.stat = source.stat

            WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN
              INSERT (stat, statdate)
              VALUES (source.stat, source.statdate)                 
                ;'
```

Comment: that part is just working fine, I need a solution for this line to match the first one `source.'+replace(refnum, 'F', '')+'`

Comment: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near 'target'.

Comment: I think substring will do the job but I dunno how to execute it I just searched it in google and currently trying it now.